# Can we get only continues slider value ?I want to minus the values that are forwarded or reverse by the user from the maximum value of slider

Tags: swift, avplayer, uislider, avplayeritem

Right now I am working on music application. I have default slider that is handle by music’s starting range and music’s total duration i.e slider’s maximum value.

If user forwarded  the music I want to minus between  starting dragged value and end dragged value from my total music’s duration .. Even  If user reverse   the music I want to minus between  starting dragged value and end dragged value from my total music’s duration.

I just want only continue music range ,because I want to minus forwarded and reverse minutes from music duration.

Comment: I think you are trying to make player with limited duration. If user moves forward or backward the duration of slider moved should be subtracted from the total duration.

Comment: @Aditya yes ..then that subtracted value I need to save in userdefault. Do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Even user do multiple time forward or backward the song.How to manage it?

Comment: You can create a timer for the total duration and close the player as the timer ends.(Even if the user do multiple time forward or backward, the Player will be played just total duration time)

Comment: I am using timer for update the slider